# Caching JSON output in PHP

Tags: php, json, caching

Got a slight bit of an issue. Been playing with the facebook and twitter API's and getting the JSON output of status search queries no problem, however I've read up further and realised that I could end up being "rate limited" as quoted from the documentation.

I was wondering is it easy to cache the JSON output each hour so that I can at least try and prevent this from happening? If so how is it done? As I tried a youtube video but that didn't really give much information only how to write the contents of a directory listing to a cache.php file, but it didn't really point out whether this can be done with JSON output and certainly didn't say how to use the time interval of 60 minutes or how to get the information then back out of the cache file.

Any help or code would be very much appreciated as there seems to be very little in tutorials on this sorta thing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here a simple function that adds caching to getting some URL contents:

```
function getJson($url) {
    // cache files are created like cache/abcdef123456...
    $cacheFile = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url);

    if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
        $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'r');
        $size = filesize($cacheFile);
        $cacheTime = trim(fgets($fh));

        // if data was cached recently, return cached data
        if ($cacheTime > strtotime('-60 minutes')) {
            return fread($fh, $size);
        }

        // else delete cache file
        fclose($fh);
        unlink($cacheFile);
    }

    $json = /* get from Twitter as usual */;

    $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, time() . "\n");
    fwrite($fh, $json);
    fclose($fh);

    return $json;
}
```

It uses the URL to identify cache files, a repeated request to the identical URL will be read from the cache the next time. It writes the timestamp into the first line of the cache file, and cached data older than an hour is discarded. It's just a simple example and you'll probably want to customize it.

Comment: That last one seems simple enough there but how would I use that on my site as. I'm still quite new to PHP and only been learning for the past year so forgive my noobness. I'm not sure what goes in the $json = /* get from twitter as usual */; part. Do I use it like so:

Comment: My code:-

`code`
$query = "i%20hate%20my%20girlfriend";
$query = urlencode($query);
$url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q={$query}&rpp=100&result_type=recent&lang=en";
$tweet = file_get_contents($url);
$tweet_array = json_decode($tweet, true);

foreach ($tweet_array['results'] as $data)
{
    $profileimg = $data['profile_image_url'];
    $postfrom = $data['from_user_name'];
    $postfromid = $data['from_user_id'];
    $created = $data['created_at'];
    $message = $data['text'];

Comment: I have left a comment with my code, I was unsure how to put it into the comments box, hopefully you will be able to copy and paste it and seperate it out so you know what it looks like. I'm a tad confused as to what to do with the function.

Comment: In your case the line `$tweet = file_get_contents($url)` gives you the raw JSON data. That's what you're looking for. In the above function, use `$json = file_get_contents($url);`. In your code, use `$tweet = getJson($url);` instead to get and cache the URL.

Comment: Cheers for that dude, appreciate the help!

Comment: This is a super useful function. I'm wondering if there's a reason you didn't make use of filemtime() to avoid writing a timestamp to each cached file? Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: @deceze  PHP Warning:  fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in getjson.php. If I add return fread($fh,'r'); The error is: fread() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Comment: The $cache_file variable needs the full directory, otherwise it will look for the cache file in the root directory.
I suggest to edit it like this:
`$cacheFile = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url);`

Comment: @JTjards No, not the root directory; it'll look relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 9):

It's a good idea to use caching to avoid the rate limit. 
Here's some example code that shows how I did it for Google+ data,
in some php code I wrote recently.

```
private function getCache($key) {
    $cache_life = intval($this->instance['cache_life']); // minutes
    if ($cache_life <= 0) return null;

    // fully-qualified filename
    $fqfname = $this->getCacheFileName($key);

    if (file_exists($fqfname)) {
        if (filemtime($fqfname) > (time() - 60 * $cache_life)) {
            // The cache file is fresh.
            $fresh = file_get_contents($fqfname);
            $results = json_decode($fresh,true);
            return $results;
        }
        else {
            unlink($fqfname);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private function putCache($key, $results) {
    $json = json_encode($results);
    $fqfname = $this->getCacheFileName($key);
    file_put_contents($fqfname, $json, LOCK_EX);
}
```

and to use it:

```
        // $cacheKey is a value that is unique to the
        // concatenation of all params. A string concatenation
        // might work. 
        $results = $this->getCache($cacheKey);
        if (!$results) {
            // cache miss; must call out
            $results = $this->getDataFromService(....);
            $this->putCache($cacheKey, $results);
        }
```

Comment: So where is the getCacheFileName function? I guess you need this if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but it show in google so for everyone looking, I made this simple one that curl a JSON url and cache it in a file that is in a specific folder, when json is requested again if 5min passed it will curl it if the 5min didnt pass yet, it will show it from file, it uses timestamp to track time and yea, enjoy

```
function ccurl($url,$id){

    $path    = "./private/cache/$id/";
    $files = scandir($path);
    $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')));
    if(count($files) > 1){
      foreach($files as $file){
        unlink($path.$file);
        $files = scandir($path);
        $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')));
      }
    }
    if(empty($files)){
      $c = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
      $response = curl_exec($c);
      curl_close ($c);

      $fp = file_put_contents($path.time().'.json', $response);
      return $response;

    }else {


      if(time() - str_replace('.json', '', $files[0]) >  300){
        unlink($path.$files[0]);
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
        $response = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close ($c);

        $fp = file_put_contents($path.time().'.json', $response);
        return $response;
      }else {
        return file_get_contents($path. $files[0]);
      }
    }
  }
```

for usage create a directory for all cached files, for me its `/private/cache` then create another directory inside for the request cache like x for example, and when calling the function it should be like htis
`ccurl('json_url','x')`
where x is the id, if u have question pls ask me ^_^ also enjoy (i might update it later so it doesn't use a directory for id