# My YouTube PHP script is heavy, how can I cache it?

Tags: php, performance, api, caching, youtube

How can I cache my YouTube PHP script on my website so it'll only request new data every hour rather than calling the data on every page load?

```
<?php
get_playlists();

function get_playlists(){
$data = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/C82EBDAC0429B6A2?                      orderby=published&max-results=12");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->entry as $playlist){
$media = $playlist->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
$attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
$thumb = $attrs['url'];
$attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
$video = $attrs['url'];
$title = substr( $media->group->title, 27);
$url = $video;

parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
$vid_Id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

$thumbnail .= '<div style="float:left; cursor:pointer;">
<p class="crop"><a class="videobox various iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' .         $vid_Id . '?autoplay=1&hd=1"><img src="' .$thumb . '" title="' . $title . '" width="74"         height="56"/></a></p></div>';
}print $thumbnail;}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching JSON output in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407514/caching-json-output-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [memcached](http://php.net/memcached) and save loaded playlists there

Comment: If your website is on a shared hosting service, then you won't have access to _memcached_.

Answer (score 0):

Setup cron job which load movies every hour. Movies info store in database. You avoid downloading and parsing XML every time. For basic speed up it will be fine.

Comment: If you don't have access to crontab, then a simpler variant is to put the playlist in a D/B with a timestamp.  Always read these from the D/B, and if the age > 1hr then refresh the list and update the table.