# Caching Twitter JSON feed in PHP

Tags: php, json, caching, twitter

I am trying to store the Twitter's JSON feed into a cache using PHP.

Here's my current script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON( "/tweetledee/userjson.php?c=10&user=HeroGreg&xrp=1&xrt=1", function(obj) { 
     $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
        $("#feed").append("<li>"+value.text+"</li><li>"+value.retweet_count+"</li><li>"+value.favorite_count+"</li><li>"+value.user.name+"</li>");
        });
     }
   });
});
```

I've searched for an answer and found this: [Caching JSON output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407514/caching-json-output-in-php), but it's a bit dated and I don't know how to adapt it to my script:

Please help? Been trying to get a twitter feed on a website for almost 2 days now...

EDIT: The PHP file that generate the JSON data is here: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/tweetledee/blob/master/tweetledee/userjson.php

Comment: where are you trying to do this cache? Because this isn't php... this is JS that happens to be making an ajax request to a php script.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. The PHP file that grabs the JSON data is this file: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/tweetledee/blob/master/tweetledee/userjson.php If that file could be modified to cache the request (limit the # of time a visitor can request the file per hour) that would work I think. I may also need to store it in a file locally to prevent having to source it out through Twitter and maxing out the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the solution can be found here: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/tweetledee/issues/35