# Caching JSON request in PHP - Cached file error

Tags: php, json, caching

I am using weatherundeground.com to get weather data but I always reach the API calls limit so I was thinking about caching the json response every 60 minutes.

This is my simple php script

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/forecast/lang:IT/q/CITY1.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

$city1 = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'display_location'}->{'city'};
```

I searched and found this answer: [Caching JSON output in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407514/caching-json-output-in-php)

I tried to merge them like this:

```
$url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/conditions/forecast/lang:IT/q/SW/Acquarossa.json";
function getJson($url) {
// cache files are created like cache/abcdef123456...
$cacheFile = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5($url) . '.json';

if (file_exists($cacheFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'r');
    $cacheTime = trim(fgets($fh));

    // if data was cached recently, return cached data
    if ($cacheTime > strtotime('-60 minutes')) {
        return fread($fh);
    }

    // else delete cache file
    fclose($fh);
    unlink($cacheFile);
}

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$fh = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, time() . "\n");
fwrite($fh, $json);
fclose($fh);

return $json;
}

$json_string = getJson($url);

$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

$city1 = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'display_location'}->{'city'};
```

I have been able to set it up and now it gets the first "round" of data, but the 2nd one and all the following, give me an error:

```
Warning: fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/*****/public_html/*****/acquarossa.php on line 27.
```

And if I put the cached json on any json validator, it says that it isn't a valid json.

( this is the cached file: http://spinnaker.url.ph/meteo/cache/1f58bbab7bf88f3f8561b769475cb7c1.json )

What can I do?

P.S.:I already CHMOD 777 the directory

Comment: Did you find the cache file on your harddrive (i.e. does it exist?). Any errors? Do you understand the code? If not, which part?

Comment: @Hirnhamster The file doesn't even get created. I think I should try to ask directly to the creator of the script of the answer( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407514/caching-json-output-in-php /user:deceze)

Comment: I have been able to set it up and now it gets the first "round" of data, but the 2nd one and all the following, give me an error:     Warning: fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u221293448/public_html/meteo/acquarossa.php on line 27. And if I put the cached json on any json validator, it says that it isn't a valid json. What can I do? ( this is the cached file: http://spinnaker.url.ph/meteo/cache/1f58bbab7bf88f3f8561b769475cb7c1.json )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the warning is pretty clear about whats going wrong. `fread()` expects 2 parameters but you're only passing on one in line 27: `return fread($fh);`

Reading the manual for [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) I guess you can fix this by changing

```
return fread($fh);
```

to

```
return fread($fh, filesize($chacheFile));
```